# How to remove file path viewer from eclipse editor view

Tags: eclipse

I looked online, but I am unable to find the answer. I am wondering how to remove the bar below the list of files that tells you the current position of a file in a project. My first picture shows the location of the bar and my second shows a close up of the bar. Thanks in advance. see image

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This is known as breadcumbs in eclipse.

Couple of ways to disable them.

1. Right click on the breadcrumb-> You will get Hide breadcrumb option ->Click on that to hide.
2. On the the action bar. There is a button called "Toggle breadcrumbs" which will disable it if it is enabled. Click on it to disable it.

[image: Action bar showing toggle breadcrumbs]

Hope it helps.

Best Regards,

Saurav